# Splitting momentJs object which contains hour x -> hour y, value to 15min objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Am I using `moment().add` wrong? Because, using my code, `dayTime2` minutes value is not getting bigger.

Goal is to add 15 minutes to `dayTime2` as long as it passes daytime's value.

Example values: (obviously I'm not using these value irl, but momentJS objects)

- `startAt` = 7 -> 7.15 -> 7.30 etc.
- `endAt` = 10

```js
var dayTime = moment.utc(endAt).format("HH:mm");
var dayTime2 = moment.utc(startAt).format("HH:mm");

while (dayTime2 <= dayTime) {
    var data = {
        title: 'VAPAA AIKA',
        type: 0,
        startsAt: dayTime2,
        endsAt: moment(dayTime2).add(30, 'minute')
    };
    moment(dayTime2).add(15, 'minute');
    console.log('TIME: ' + dayTime2);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not using moment the right way.

First of all, to create a moment object from a string not in ISO 8601 format use [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) or if your input is a number you can use [`moment({unit: value, ...});`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/) specifing units (like `hours`).

Then **do not** compare string, but you should use moment [comparing functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) like [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/).

Another problem with your code is that `moment(dayTime2).add(15, 'minute')` creates a new moment object, but you need to modify `dayTime2` itself. Use `dayTime2.add(15, 'minute')` instead.

Note that moment object are mutable, so you have to use [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/), if you don't want to change original value (for example when you set `endsAt` property of `data` object).

Here a working example:

```js
var startAt = 7;
var endAt = '10';
var dayTime = moment.utc(endAt, 'h');
var dayTime2 = moment.utc({h: startAt});

while (dayTime2.isBefore(dayTime)) {
  var data = {
    title: 'VAPAA AIKA',
    type: 0,
    startsAt: dayTime2.format('HH:mm'),
    endsAt: dayTime2.clone().add(30, 'minute').format('HH:mm')
  };
  dayTime2.add(15, 'minute');
  console.log('TIME: ' + dayTime2.format('HH:mm'));
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```